# Can we control flag settings?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I was marking [a question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16432/1542) as off-topic and the modal made me choose only between these two options:

- *belongs to meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com*
- *belongs to stackoverflow.com*

Is that list automatically generated or we have control over it? In case we do, it would be helpful to add also

- *belongs to cs.stackexchange.com*

This is something that we would want every time the question is not a research question.

Comment: I agree, but cs is not among the options because cs is still beta.  See Shog9’s answer to the linked question.

Comment: ah, I see, it will be possible when CS.SE will be out of beta. Thanks @TsuyoshiIto